# Why are a couple words in Ma'oz Tzur different in some sidduriim?

Tags: chanuka, grammar-dikduk, song-poetry, translation, nuschaot

The Text I am referring to is:

> רָעוֹת שָׂבְעָה נַפְשִׁי, בְּיָגוֹן כֹּחִי **כָּלָה**
>   חַיַּי מֵרְרוּ בְקֹשִׁי, בְּשִׁעְבּוּד מַלְכוּת עֶגְלָה
>   וּבְיָדוֹ הַגְּדוֹלָה הוֹצִיא אֶת הַסְּגֻלָּה
>   חֵיל פַּרְעֹה וְכָל זַרְעוֹ יָרְדוּ כְּאֶבֶן **בִּמְצוּלָה** .

---

Transliteration:

> Ra'ot sav'ah nafshi, byagon kohi **kala**.
>   Hayai mareru bkoshi, beshi'abud malkhut egla.
>   Uvyado hagdola hotzi et hasgula.
>   Heil par'o vekhol zar'o yardu ke'even **bimtzula**.

---

The bolded words are sometimes different.

I have seen the 1st one as `Kila` instead of `Kala`
I have also seen the 2nd one as `MeTzulah` instead of `BimTzulah`

What is the difference in the translation?
Is there a difference?

Comment: There are a bunch of other words that are slightly different, most likely small changes in transcription over history...

Comment: @AviD: Plus, there are two completely differing versions of the last stanza, one of which is (I understand) due to censorship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Kila* means "he/it ended" (transitive), here "he/it cut off my strength"; *kala* means "he/it ended" (intransitive), here "my strength cut out".

*Yar'du k'even bimtzula* means "sank like a stone in the [depths?]"; *yar'du k'even m'tzula* means "sank like a stone to the [depths?]". (Hebrew frequently drops the prefixed *l-* or suffixed *-a* that indicates a destination.) *Yar'du k'even m'tzula* could also mean "sank like a stone of the [depths?]" (i.e., "sank like the [depths?]' stone"), but that seems less likely to me.